# SQL query to use in ireport to report user feedback

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a trouble with my query. I have actually a database with this setup:
[DB SETUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esfYP.png)
I use it to insert my data from a feedback machine. The data provided is like this example:

    `R;  Identifier
    P34567; Research Number
    05/05/2015; Research Date
    10:32:39;   Research Time
    02; Question Number (2-5)
    04; User evaluation (1-5). 
    333 Colaborator ID`

I need to build a report for each colaborator and a general report showing all colaborators from a sector. This sector stuff is not yet implemented so I'm considering all data from a single sector.

I built a query that works with a few lines in my db, but when it is executed in a full DB it stucks.

To retrieve data for each colaborator I'm using:

```
select p.pergunta as Pergunta,
(select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and colaborador= 
$P{colaborador} and resposta=1) as '1 - Excelente',
(select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and colaborador= 
$P{colaborador} and resposta=2) as '2 - Muito Bom',
(select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and colaborador= 
$P{colaborador} and resposta=3) as '3 - Bom',
(select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and colaborador= 
$P{colaborador} and resposta=4) as '4 - Regular',
(select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and colaborador= 
$P{colaborador} and resposta=5) as '5 - Ruim',
(select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and colaborador= 
$P{colaborador} and (resposta=1 or resposta=2 or resposta=3 or resposta=4 
or resposta=5)) as 'TOTAL'
from pesquisa as p where colaborador=$P{colaborador} and data between 
$P{data_inicial} and $P{data_final}
group by pergunta;
```

With this code I can create this report :[Colaborator Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR1EB.png)

For the General report I'm using this query:

```
select p.colaborador, p.pergunta as Pergunta,
(select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and resposta=1)         
as '1 - Excelente',
(select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and resposta=2) 
 as '2 - Muito Bom',
 (select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and resposta=3) 
 as '3 - Bom',
 (select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and resposta=4) 
 as '4 - Regular',
 (select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and resposta=5) 
 as '5 - Ruim',
 (select count(*) from pesquisa where pergunta=p.pergunta and colaborador 
 = p.colaborador and (resposta=1 or resposta=2 or resposta=3 or 
 resposta=4 or resposta=5)) as 'TOTAL'
 from pesquisa as p
 group by colaborador, pergunta;
```

The report is generated and this is the result: Can't post more imagens

As i said with a few lines it works perfectly but with a large data it stucks, and I dunno how to get this result with another query. The reason I'm using all of those selects is to count through rows the answers for each question.

Can you guys give me a light?

Comment: I tried adding indexes on the data and colaborator fields to optimize it, But nothing has changed, so I'm thinking my query is wrong =/

Comment: I got my answer, after trying with indexes and almost no performance change i changed my count(*) to count(resposta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend show me another way to achiev this result.
Basically it subselect the data end filter again to display it.

```
SELECT colaborador, 
   pergunta,
   SUM(EXCELENTE) AS '1 - EXCELENTE',
   SUM(MUITOBOM) AS '2 - MUITO BOM',
   SUM(BOM) AS '3 - BOM',
   SUM(REGULAR) AS '4 - REGULAR',
   SUM(RUIM) AS '5 - RUIM'
FROM (
  SELECT colaborador, 
         pergunta,
         CASE WHEN resposta = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'EXCELENTE',
         CASE WHEN resposta = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'MUITOBOM',
         CASE WHEN resposta = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'BOM',
         CASE WHEN resposta = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'REGULAR',
         CASE WHEN resposta = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'RUIM'
  FROM pesquisa
  WHERE data between str_to_date($P{data_inicial}, "%d/%m/%Y") and str_to_date($P{data_final}, "%d/%m/%Y")
        and colaborador = $P{colaborador}
) AS A
GROUP BY colaborador, pergunta
```

It is way better and faster.